# What do the number codes mean in active profiles in terminal on macbook pro?

Tags: macos, terminal, macbook, power, osx-lion

Is there somewhere that says what the numbers mean?  Specifically I want to know what the -1 is by AC Power, it used to be a 2.

```
Suprise:~ Marty$ sudo pmset -g  
Password:  
Active Profiles:  
Battery Power           -1  
AC Power                -1*  
Currently in use:  
 standbydelay   4200  
 standby        0  
 womp           1  
 halfdim        1  
 panicrestart   157680000  
 hibernatefile  /var/vm/sleepimage  
 sms            1  
 networkoversleep       0  
 disksleep      10  
 sleep          10  
 hibernatemode  3  
 ttyskeepawake  1  
 displaysleep   10  
 acwake         0  
 lidwake        1
```

Comment: i did get AC power back to 2, but still wondering what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number behind the profile name refers to the index of the used profile, from the list displayed when using `pmset -g profiles`. If the number is `-1`, a customized profile is used instead (this means you modified your **Energy Saver** preferences from the default settings).

The asterisk denotes the profile currently being applied (battery or AC).

The remaining settings are explained in `man pmset`, section **SETTINGS**.